# Validate credit card expiration with angular?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-filters

I can not validate my date field.

The idea is that when the user enter the date validate if the card is expired. I made this directive but I am a little lost with the directives of angular.

```js
  checkOut.directive('cardDateExpiration', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(date) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var m, y, d;

        if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/.test(date)) {
          m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
          y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
          d = new Date(y, m);
        } else if (/^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
          m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
          y = date.slice(-4);
          d = new Date(y, m);
        } else if (/^\d{4}$/.test(date)) {
          m = date.substring(0, 2) - 1;
          y = 20 + date.slice(-2);
          d = new Date(y, m);
        }

        return currentDate > d;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="large-6 columns sd-items-form">
  <label>
    <input id="expiry_date" maxlength="5" name="datacard" card-date-expiration ng-disabled="" class="sd-field sd-txt-center p-l-0" ng-model="form.data.datacard" type="text" type placeholder="MM / YY" required></input>
  </label>
  <div class="error" ng-if="checkoutPayment.$submitted || checkoutPayment.datacard.$touched" ng-messages="checkoutPayment.datacard.$error">
    <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">Not valid date credit card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this example of how to do custom validation of input fields in angular here: http://jsfiddle.net/fortesl/2uv6xmjL/6/
I am using momentjs to validate a date, which I recommend, but you can also parse the input string if you like (I do not recommend it). Code is shown below:

```
app.directive('dateFieldValidator', [function () {
var validateDate = function (date, format) {
    if (!date.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return moment(date, format.toUpperCase(), true).isValid();
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        dateFormat: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        //For DOM -> model validation
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = validateDate(value, scope.dateFormat);
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validDate', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        //For Model Update --> DOM
        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = validateDate(value, scope.dateFormat);
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('validDate', valid);
            return value;
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

and here is a sample html which uses the directive:

```
<div ng-app="dateApp">
<div ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
    <form name="dateForm" novalidate
    ng-submit="dateCtrl.setDate(dateForm.dateInput.$valid); dateForm.dateInput.$setPristine();">
        Enter date:
        <input name="dateInput" ng-model="dateCtrl.date" date-format="{{dateCtrl.format}}" 
        date-field-validator placeholder="{{dateCtrl.format}}">
        <button ng-disabled="dateForm.dateInput.$pristine">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

A sample controller:

```
var app = angular.module('dateApp', []);
```

app.controller('DateController', function () {
    var self = this;

```
self.format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
self.date = '';

self.setDate = function (valid) {
    if (valid) {
        window.alert('You entered a valid Date: ' + self.date);
    } else {
        window.alert('!!!!!!!!!! WARNING: INVALID DATE !!!!!!!!!');
    }
    self.date = '';
}
```

})